# Naudio Reader<WaveStream> list crash issue [Race condition]

Tags: c#, multithreading, naudio, naudio-framework

I have a `Webstream reader<WaveStream> list` and I am disposing WaveStream using foreach loop as mention below

```
foreach (WaveStream ws in readers)
    ws.Dispose();
```

but `reader<WaveStream> list` is modified by another method at the same time when foreach loop disposing the object
hence we got unhandled exception collection was modified by another method and our application crashed

could you please provide some explanation or explanation link how our crash issue resolved after using for loop as mentioned below?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= readers.ToArray().Length - 1; i++)
{
   readers[i].Dispose();
}
```

I am not able to understand how for loop and `readers.ToArray()` resolved the crash issue.

Answer (score 0):

If a `List<T>` is modified while you `foreach` through it, you will get an exception, as the underlying collection has changed. So in your case either another thread was changing the list while you iterated through it, or the very action of Disposing streams was modifying the list. By calling `ToArray` you create a new array which is a copy of the original list. No one else has access to that array so its contents will not change while you iterate through it.